# Notification in ajax response orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I'm using ajax requests to get one of PartialViews in my project. I want to pass a message by INotifier.
Cuttently i'm using HttpStatusCodeResult `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(204, "Message");`to pass informations about the errors but is not satisfying solution.

```
 $(this).load($(this).attr("href"), function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (xhr.status == 204) {
            // show message
        }
    });
```

I'm wondering that is possible by using standard `INotifier.Error()` in ActionResult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. The default notifier is not suitable for AJAX requests. What it does, it queues notifications inside a temporary collection. Queued notifications are then written to the client when request ends - pushed into `Layout.Messages` zone.

In your case it would be best to implement your own `INotifier` that would follow the required logic. It's a very simple interface to implement so it's not actually that much work.

Answer (score -1):

I needn't to implement INotifier, i only placed in my PartialView this:

```
@Display(WorkContext.Layout.Zones["Messages"])
```

Now the message isn't rendered in main zone (in Layout.cshtml of used theme), but could be placed anywhere in your PartialView, for example under the affected table.